# 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

Tags: numpy

I get the error as in the title of my post.  I have seen this come up in other questions, but I am interested in understanding what this means since the other answers were in a specific context that does not apply to me.

Secondly, I would like to understand how this applies to my code, shown below.  Note that this all works OK if Zindx = 0, but not for any other case.

```
    Zindx = list(E).index(0)
    for m in range(0,N):
            if m != Zindx:
                for n in range(0,N):
                    if n != Zindx:
                        if n != m:
                            x[m,m] = x[m,m] (
                            - (E[n]-E[m] + E[n])*x[m,n]*x[n,Zindx]
                            /x[m,Zindx]/E[m]
                            )
```

Comment: Your problem is where you do `x[m, m] = x[m, m] ( ... )`. You probably want to stick a `*`, or some other operator, between `x[m, m]` and the `(`: otherwise, Python is interpreting that as calling object `x[m, m]` with the arguments inside the parentheses.

Comment: Now I feel stupid super stupid!  Thamks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
x[m,m] (
    - (E[n]-E[m] + E[n])*x[m,n]*x[n,Zindx]
    /x[m,Zindx]/E[m]
    )
```

Is trying to call `x[m,m]` as a function with the expression within the parenthesis as an argument.  I am guessing `x[m,m]` returns a `float`.
Do you mean to multiply `x[m,m]` by the term in the parenthesis?  If so, add the `*`.

Comment: Yeh, that was very stupid of me.  I read that parentheses can be used for equations that run on multiple lines, but clearly this can only work if they are used with the same syntax.  I was too busy looking at all the other possibilities that I never noticed...